# Why Vertex and Fragment Shaders not compiling?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, glsl, shader

I'm working on Shaders with R3F. However, something was wrong with this project and I couldn't find it after hours of trying. I'm writing the codes of the GLSL files that I got an error with below.

I want to create a cloud image for this project. I got this work from [Codrops](https://github.com/dghez/THREEJS_Procedural-clouds).

**Vertex GLSL**

```
uniform float rotation;
uniform vec2 center;
#include <common>
#include <uv_pars_vertex>
#include <fog_pars_vertex>
#include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
#include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    // #include <uv_vertex>
  vUv = uv;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec2 scale;
    scale.x = length( vec3( modelMatrix[ 0 ].x, modelMatrix[ 0 ].y, modelMatrix[ 0 ].z ) );
    scale.y = length( vec3( modelMatrix[ 1 ].x, modelMatrix[ 1 ].y, modelMatrix[ 1 ].z ) );

    vec2 alignedPosition = ( position.xy - ( center - vec2( 0.5 ) ) ) * scale;
    vec2 rotatedPosition;
    rotatedPosition.x = cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x - sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
    rotatedPosition.y = sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x + cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
    mvPosition.xy += rotatedPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
    #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
    #include <fog_vertex>
}
```

**Fragment GLSL**

```
#pragma glslify: fbm3d = require('glsl-fractal-brownian-noise/3d')
#pragma glslify: snoise3 = require('glsl-noise/simplex/3d')
#pragma glslify: levels = require('./levels.glsl')

uniform sampler2D uTxtShape;
uniform sampler2D uTxtCloudNoise;
uniform float uTime;

uniform float uFac1;
uniform float uFac2;
uniform float uTimeFactor1;
uniform float uTimeFactor2;
uniform float uDisplStrenght1;
uniform float uDisplStrenght2;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec2 newUv = vUv;

    vec4 txtNoise1 = texture2D(uTxtCloudNoise, vec2(vUv.x + uTime * 0.0001, vUv.y - uTime * 0.00014)); // noise txt
    vec4 txtNoise2 = texture2D(uTxtCloudNoise, vec2(vUv.x - uTime * 0.00002, vUv.y + uTime * 0.000017 + 0.2)); // noise txt

    float noiseBig = fbm3d(vec3(vUv * uFac1, uTime * uTimeFactor1), 4)+ 1.0 * 0.5;
    newUv += noiseBig * uDisplStrenght1;

    float noiseSmall = snoise3(vec3(newUv * uFac2, uTime * uTimeFactor2));

    newUv += noiseSmall * uDisplStrenght2;

    vec4 txtShape = texture2D(uTxtShape, newUv);

    float alpha = levels((txtNoise1 + txtNoise2) * 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7).r;
    alpha *= txtShape.r;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.95,0.95,0.95), alpha);
}
```

**The error is from console:**

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 1282 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

VERTEX

ERROR: 0:57: '/' : syntax error


  52: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
  53:   attribute vec4 skinIndex;
  54:   attribute vec4 skinWeight;
  55: #endif
  56: 
> 57: /static/media/cloudVert.41ee4f902e06f79518ac.glsl
FRAGMENT

ERROR: 0:69: '/' : syntax error


  64: vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) {
  65:   return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb * 12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.a );
  66: }
  67: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearTosRGB( value ); }
  68: 
> 69: /static/media/cloudFrag.6e430067cf79fd904c61.glsl
```

And I get same error for cloudVert file.

Comment: That looks like your compiler is adding the *path to the file* instead of adding its *actual GLSL contents*. That's what you're seeing on line 57. You might need to look into your bundler settings. For example, I use Webpack, which users [shader-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shader-loader) to successfully import the text content inside a `.glsl` file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a variable to store file script.

for example.

```
var _VS = `
uniform float rotation;
uniform vec2 center;
#include <common>
#include <uv_pars_vertex>
#include <fog_pars_vertex>
#include <logdepthbuf_pars_vertex>
#include <clipping_planes_pars_vertex>

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    // #include <uv_vertex>
  vUv = uv;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    vec2 scale;
    scale.x = length( vec3( modelMatrix[ 0 ].x, modelMatrix[ 0 ].y, modelMatrix[ 0 ].z ) );
    scale.y = length( vec3( modelMatrix[ 1 ].x, modelMatrix[ 1 ].y, modelMatrix[ 1 ].z ) );

    vec2 alignedPosition = ( position.xy - ( center - vec2( 0.5 ) ) ) * scale;
    vec2 rotatedPosition;
    rotatedPosition.x = cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x - sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
    rotatedPosition.y = sin( rotation ) * alignedPosition.x + cos( rotation ) * alignedPosition.y;
    mvPosition.xy += rotatedPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    #include <logdepthbuf_vertex>
    #include <clipping_planes_vertex>
    #include <fog_vertex>
}
`;

var _FS = `
#pragma glslify: fbm3d = require('glsl-fractal-brownian-noise/3d')
#pragma glslify: snoise3 = require('glsl-noise/simplex/3d')
#pragma glslify: levels = require('./levels.glsl')

uniform sampler2D uTxtShape;
uniform sampler2D uTxtCloudNoise;
uniform float uTime;

uniform float uFac1;
uniform float uFac2;
uniform float uTimeFactor1;
uniform float uTimeFactor2;
uniform float uDisplStrenght1;
uniform float uDisplStrenght2;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec2 newUv = vUv;

    vec4 txtNoise1 = texture2D(uTxtCloudNoise, vec2(vUv.x + uTime * 0.0001, vUv.y - uTime * 0.00014)); // noise txt
    vec4 txtNoise2 = texture2D(uTxtCloudNoise, vec2(vUv.x - uTime * 0.00002, vUv.y + uTime * 0.000017 + 0.2)); // noise txt

    float noiseBig = fbm3d(vec3(vUv * uFac1, uTime * uTimeFactor1), 4)+ 1.0 * 0.5;
    newUv += noiseBig * uDisplStrenght1;

    float noiseSmall = snoise3(vec3(newUv * uFac2, uTime * uTimeFactor2));

    newUv += noiseSmall * uDisplStrenght2;

    vec4 txtShape = texture2D(uTxtShape, newUv);

    float alpha = levels((txtNoise1 + txtNoise2) * 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7).r;
    alpha *= txtShape.r;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.95,0.95,0.95), alpha);
}
`;
```

It should work